# Customizing filters for ycommercewebservices using AddOn support (Hybris 5.1)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm using addon support in hybris 5.1 to customize ycommercewebservices and I don't see any way to add or modify HTTP filters because web.xml from addon is ignored during synchronizing addon and its target. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't customise template extensions. And why is this not on the forum?

Comment: Does it violate some rules? However thanks, I will consider moving to forum. It seems like there is no hybris developers here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, it was easy - just redeclare filters with the same id as in ycommercewebservices-web-spring.xml, but in your addon-web-spring.xml:

```
<bean id="baseSiteFilter" class="my.own.SelectBaseSiteFilter" >
        <property name="baseSiteFilterExclusions" ref="baseSiteFilterExclusions" />
        <property name="configurationService"  ref="configurationService" />
        <property name="sessionService" ref="sessionService" />
        <property name="baseSiteService" ref="baseSiteService" />
</bean>
```

And if you need to add new filter or exclude default filters, redeclare commerceWebServicesFilterChainList in your addon-web-spring.xml:

```
<alias name="defaultCommerceWebServicesFilterChainList" alias="commerceWebServicesFilterChainList" />
    <util:list id="defaultCommerceWebServicesFilterChainList">
        <!-- generic platform filters -->
        <ref bean="log4jFilter" />
        <ref bean="tenantActivationFilter"/>
        <ref bean="sessionFilter"/>

        <!-- commerceWebservices filters -->
        <ref bean="baseSiteFilter" />
        <ref bean="sessionAttributesFilter" />

        <!-- Security -->
        <ref bean="springSecurityFilterChain"/>

    </util:list>
```

Also don't forget to add following line to project.properties.template before installing addon:

```
ycommercewebservices.additionalWebSpringConfigs.youroccaddon=classpath:/youroccaddon/web/spring/youroccaddon-web-spring.xml
```

youroccaddon-web-spring.xml will be added in spring context after ycommercewebservices-web-spring.xml, so it's possible to override beans from ycommercewebservices context.

Comment: See, this is silly. Don't customise template extensions. GENERATE FROM THEM and then customise.

Comment: Do you know the concept of addon in hybris? This is preferred way to use storefront extensions.

Comment: Heard of them? Pff. If only you knew. And if you re-declare the filterchain like that then you can't have any other addons. We gave lists like that IDs so you can use the ListMergeDirectiveBeanPostProcessor and have them play nice.

Comment: Is there anyway to customize an addon that isn't a template?